# Notice: Undefined index: hover

Tags: php, wordpress, user-interface, themes

I'm getting this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: hover in /home/fairdealoverseas/public_html/wp-content/themes/visahub/option-tree/theme-interface.php on line 167

I couldn't find any solution online.

Here is the code:

```
if( !function_exists( 'VisaHub_option_tree_link_value' ) ){

    function VisaHub_option_tree_link_value( $class, $color, $key ){
      if( $key == '' or $class == '' or $color == '' ) return;

      if( VisaHub_option( $key ) ){
         return sprintf( '%1$s{ %2$s:%3$s; }
                            %1$s:hover{ %2$s:%4$s; }
                                %1$s:active { %2$s:%5$s; }
                                    %1$s:visited { %2$s:%6$s; }
                                      %1$s:focus { %2$s:%7$s; }',
                    $class, $color,
                    VisaHub_option( $key )['link'],
                    VisaHub_option( $key )['hover'],
                    VisaHub_option( $key )['active'],
                    VisaHub_option( $key )['visited'],
                    VisaHub_option( $key )['focus']
                );
        }
    }
}
```